# Install 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit machine via Multiarch?

Tags: debian

I am installing Intel® C++ Composer XE for Linux on Debian Wheezy 64-bit. During the installation it reports:

```
32-bit libraries not found
32-bit libraries not found on this system.
This product release requires the presence of 32-bit compatibility libraries when running on Intel(R) 64 architecture systems. One or more of these libraries could not be found:
libstdc++ (including libstdc++6)
glibc
libgcc
Without these libraries, the compiler and the debugger will not function properly. Please refer to Release Notes for more information.
```

So I

```
$ dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ aptitude update
$ aptitude install libstdc++-4.8-dev:i386
```

but then messages on conflicts flood:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils:i386{ab} cpp:i386{ab} cpp-4.8:i386{ab} gcc:i386{ab} 
  gcc-4.8:i386{ab} gcc-4.8-base:i386{a} libasan0:i386{a} libatomic1:i386{a} 
  libc6:i386{a} libc6-dev:i386{a} libc6-i686:i386{a} libcloog-isl4:i386{a} 
  libgcc-4.8-dev:i386{a} libgcc1:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a} libgomp1:i386{a} 
  libisl10:i386{a} libitm1:i386{a} libmpc3:i386{a} libmpfr4:i386{a} 
  libquadmath0:i386{a} libstdc++-4.8-dev:i386 libstdc++6:i386{a} 
  linux-libc-dev:i386{a} zlib1g:i386{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 24.7 MB of archives. After unpacking 105 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-4.8 : Conflicts: cpp-4.8:i386 but 4.8.2-15 is to be installed.
 cpp-4.8:i386 : Conflicts: cpp-4.8 but 4.8.2-15 is installed.
 binutils : Conflicts: binutils:i386 but 2.24-3 is to be installed.
 binutils:i386 : Conflicts: binutils but 2.24-3 is installed.
 gcc : Conflicts: gcc:i386 but 4:4.8.2-2 is to be installed.
 gcc:i386 : Conflicts: gcc but 4:4.8.2-2 is installed.
 cpp : Conflicts: cpp:i386 but 4:4.8.2-2 is to be installed.
 cpp:i386 : Conflicts: cpp but 4:4.8.2-2 is installed.
 gcc-4.8 : Conflicts: gcc-4.8:i386 but 4.8.2-15 is to be installed.
 gcc-4.8:i386 : Conflicts: gcc-4.8 but 4.8.2-15 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version: 
1)     binutils:i386 [Not Installed]                       
2)     cpp:i386 [Not Installed]                            
3)     cpp-4.8:i386 [Not Installed]                        
4)     gcc:i386 [Not Installed]                            
5)     gcc-4.8:i386 [Not Installed]                        

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:          
6)     libc6-dev:i386 recommends gcc:i386 | c-compiler:i386


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Am I doing this right? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to install `ia32-libs` ?

Answer (score 0):

You generally only need to install the 32-bit runtime libraries for a 32-bit program to run.  Leave out the -dev.